# Global variable undefined in javascript function that follows

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables, scope

I had some code that essentially was like this:

```
TestFunction();
const pi = 3.14;

function TestFunction()
{
    alert("pi="+pi);
}
```

The code failed because 'pi' was undefined. I scratched my head for a long time but then realized that the code was not being parsed linearly. When the function was called, the function "TestFunction" was parsed, but the constant had not yet been parsed.

This occurred with Safari and Chrome. I don't know if all browsers would parse in the same way. It might work with some.

Comment: `const` and `let` declarations aren't [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) like `var` and `function` declarations are.

Comment: The constant was parsed, but it doesn't get assigned until you execute the statement.

Comment: I guess I was "hoisted" on my own petard.

Comment: @4castle It's actually just like `var`. The declaration is parsed, so the variable scope is known, but the initialization doesn't happen until you execute the statement.

Comment: The exact same behaviour does occur with var as well as const.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, I just found the documentation on the [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone).

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong. And it also applies to [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Answer (score 1):

Moving the definition of the constant before the first call to the function solved the problem.

```
const pi = 3.14;

TestFunction();

function TestFunction()
{
    alert("pi="+pi);
}
```